# Is using inline-block instead of float for displaying block elements in a row safe?

Tags: html, css

As browsers get more and more enhanced is it safe to use inline-block nowadays instead of floating?

For example, I want to display 3 div blocks in a row. I can either either float them or set them to `inline-block`.

I'm used to floating but it looks `inline-block` is the way to go nowadays. Is that so?

Comment: float and inline-block do very different things. Use the appropriate one.

Comment: What do you mean by "safe"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fast answer is: Yes ...

Look at support here: http://caniuse.com/#search=inline-block

Comment: Does it mean I could have been using inline-block since IE9 for the last 10 years???

Comment: Arrrrr ... hehe ... maybe :)